# Plotly problem of specifying point symbol within the boxplot

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to specify the point symbol (shape) based on a factor, so that the point shape within the boxplot can be different (which can be very useful for highlighting a group of points). However, it looks like instead of showing different shapes, the third boxplot got split into two boxes.

Can you please advise how to achieve that?

```
data(iris)

iris=mutate(iris, Petal.Width_high=ifelse(Petal.Width>2,"High","Low"))

iris %>% plot_ly(x = ~ Species, y = ~ Petal.Width, color= ~ Species,
                 symbol = ~ Petal.Width_high,
                 type = "box", mode="markers",boxpoints="all",
                 jitter = 0.4, marker = list(size = 10),
                 pointpos = 0,hoverinfo='text',
                 text= ~paste('</br>Species: ', Species,
                              '</br>Petal.Width: ', Petal.Width))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do one plot first and then `add_markers` afterwards. Something like:

```
p <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~ Species, y = ~ Petal.Width, 
          type = "box", 
          hoverinfo='text',
          text= ~paste('</br>Species: ', Species,
                       '</br>Petal.Width: ', Petal.Width))

add_markers(p, symbol = ~ Petal.Width_high, marker = list(size = 10))
```

---